# NodeJS response takes a long time

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, server, request

I've made a simple request but sometimes, it takes a long time to get an answer. Chome DevTools shows me that TTFB (Time To First Byte) is often more than 10 seconds.

[image]

Here is my query. I'm using `express` and `mysql` modules.

```
  module.getSessionToken = function(request, response) {
       bddConnection.query(
           `SELECT id, firstname, lastname
            FROM users
            WHERE password = "${request.query.password}"
            AND mail = "${request.query.mail}"`,
           function(err, res) {
               if (err) throw err;
               response.send(res);
           }
       );
   };
```

This is the only request of my server with that issue. The others are working well.

Comment: execute same query in mysql query browser and check how much time it takes to execute

Comment: @AJS It's working well on mysql query browser, I think It's a server side issue

Comment: Where is the application hosted, or are you running it locally? What other middleware are you using? You could add debug lines with timestamps to track where the time is spent.

Comment: I've noticed the same issue on a production build we have. We use PM2 for cluster deployments and it's only an issue in production, not locally or with a direct MySQL connection. Will update if we figure out the issue.

Comment: Any solution found? @k26dr @Valentin?